# Does Yocto's OS compatibility list apply to all Yocto releases?

Tags: ubuntu, yocto

In our project (a bit outside our influence) the Yocto Warrior is used in combination with Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS) (so not the latest Yocto version). Officially this linux distri is compatible with Yocto, but does anyone know if this compatibility is only formally assured when using the latest Yocto version?

Comment: No, it is unique for each release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.7.4/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#detailed-supported-distros

2.7.4 version is the latest (and last) dot release of Warrior branch. The link points to the distros officially supported for that release of Yocto Project.